# How to reload a page at certain hour and only once a day

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that runs every one minute.

```
setInterval(function(){

  //first, check time, if it is 9 AM, reload the page
   var now = new Date();
   if (now.getHours() == 9 {
      window.refresh();
   }

  //do other stuff

},60000);
```

Now the problem is, I want the reload to happen only once a day. since the function runs every minutes, so next time it fires up, it will reload the page again if it is between 9AM and 10AM. How do I make the reload happen only once?

I can probably do it by creating another interval function that fires every hour and check if I should reload. but since I already have the above function that runs every minute, can I do it from there?

If I do end up with creating another function that checks every hour. What will happen if those 2 functions fire up at the exact same time?

Comment: Do you only want it to happen once per user? Or once overall?

Comment: I would like to see a good answer for this.

Comment: once a day for each user. so if the webpage keep running, it will reload at 9 am today, and then reload at 9 am tomorrow...

Comment: I don't understand, why do you need this refresh? You have to know that the time is Client side, i.e. 9 am here, can be 12am there. And the refresh only works for users current visiting your webpage, depending of the timezone.

Comment: @RG-3 What about mine?

Comment: I suspect it is a mechanism to automatically load the newest version of the page every day. @JeffersonHenriqueC.Soares

Comment: @JeffersonHenriqueC.Soares: He wants to get the page refreshed every day. That is his problem, why he want to do it? Or why he needs it. No 'Pun' intended.

Comment: @11684: Great ans man!!!

Comment: We need to know @RG-3, do you don't know why? Because his problem can be another thing, we are in Stackoverflow to solve somebody problem, not only answer a question, you need to undestand this. We are here to help, not to only answer

Comment: `window.refresh()` doesn't do anything - you need `location.reload()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would store the date of the last refresh, calculate the difference, and it it's less than 6 hours (to be safe) you won't need a refresh.

```
var lastRefresh = new Date(); // If the user just loaded the page you don't want to refresh either

setInterval(function(){

  //first, check time, if it is 9 AM, reload the page
   var now = new Date();
   if (now.getHours() == 9 && new Date() - lastRefresh > 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6) { // If it is between 9 and ten AND the last refresh was longer ago than 6 hours refresh the page.
      location.reload();
   }

  //do other stuff

},60000);
```

I hope this is what you meant. Note this is untested.

Comment: can't check for lastRefresh as the page refresh will remove all javascript variables...

Comment: Oops... Sorry! Wait a sec. @TheZuck

Comment: oh wait you're actually right, since the refresh will get your code to run so lastRefresh is actually correct :)  not sure about the rest of the code, but lastRefresh is actually the last time the page was refreshed

Comment: Haha, I was confused too and working on an edit involving some `sessionStorage` code... @TheZuck

Comment: this won't work without fixing it though, because you want the delta to be MORE than not less than a day.

Comment: Thanks! I am afraid I didn't really wake up today, I'm reversing this kind of things the whole day and making really weird spelling errors... @TheZuck

Comment: I have to admit this is a cleaner solution than storing in a cookie (the way I suggested), so my vote's for yours.

Comment: @11684: How you are going to store the value of lastRefresh? I mean how you are storing it?

Comment: There's no need to store. whenever the page get refreshed, the time get assigned as lastRefresh time.

Comment: @RG-3 If the user loads the page, that counts as a refresh too.

Comment: 6 hours is mentioned in the code comment, but the code as it stands only prevents a refresh if *60* hours has elapsed. Does the last 60 need changing to 6?

Comment: @11684 Also, `window.refresh()` does not work in IE, Chrome or Firefox. `location.reload()` however, worked in all those browsers.  So I can only assume window.refresh() is a custom function you've written or you're using a really weird browser - can't find anything about window.refresh() on the internet?

Comment: @NickG I just used it as a placeholder for a real (existing) refresh function. The snippet is just to get the idea across, it was never meant to be a "plug-and-play solution".

Comment: OK, but if you change that to `location.reload()` it will work fine :)

Comment: Additionally, it's not good practice to include code in an answer which looks like it it's literal code which should work, when it won't. If you wanted to have a placeholder, then put `// TODO: put code here to reload`.  But thanks for the answer - I have upvoted.

Comment: Sorry just realised you took that line from the OP's question. Still might be good to change your example.

Answer (score 1):

without going into more complex solutions for getting this done in a nicer way, you can use getDay() and save it in a cookie so that you can check if the last time this method was called it was with the same day, this way only a day after you'll be at 9am and in a different day.

Comment: But I never knew about `getDay()`! (But I never really looked into Date objects.) Nice answer too!

Answer (score -4):

It is in C#. The algorithm will be:

1. Create a timer in C# where it runs at Nth hour (eg. 10:00 AM, 14:00 PM, etc.)
2. You check whether the time is X hour or not (in this case 9:00 AM).
3. If it is, then you refresh the page.

Comment: I never heard of client side C# on a webpage and if it's server side, how are you going to find out which client you want to send a refresh to? HTTP is stateless (I'm not sure if that's the correct term), so the client disconnects as soon as he got the page...

Comment: It is server side. So if I am creating a timer on that page, that timer will load every 9:00 AM.

Comment: Yes, the timer will fire, and then what? You can't keep track of which users are on that page, as I already pointed out, so you can't send the right clients a refresh. Doing this server-side is very impractical, if you can do this client-side too. It is probably better for the user experience too, what if a user loads the page at 8:59? He's reading something and suddenly gets a page refresh. With my approach, that won't happen.

Comment: You cannot refresh a page from the server side. Please post a code example if you think this can be done.