# reload the page every exact hour

Tags: javascript

I have a page that should reload every hour exactly (so at 8:00 am, 9:00 am and so on). The page is displayed on a device with no user interaction that can be turned on at any time. So for example it can be turned on at 8:45 am but the first reload must be at 9:00 am in any case. This means that a simple setTimeout with 3.600.000 milliseconds is not the right choice. 
My actual code is this:

```
complete: function() {
    setTimeout(location.reload(),3600000 - ((new Date) % 3600000));
}
```

Is this the best way to get the result? Is this error safe during all the hours of the day? I am still learning when it comes to dates in javascript so thanks for the help!

Comment: now you call reload before passing to `setTimeout`, it should be `setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3600000 - ((new Date) % 3600000));`, or `setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location),3600000 - ((new Date) % 3600000));`

Comment: @Barmar thanks! I can't test my app since the devices are not yet available and I want to be sure that everything is working fine as I think

Comment: @Grundy what do you mean?

Comment: I think your code is fine

Comment: @LelioFaieta, now you pass to `setTimeout` - `location.reload()` so execute this func before passing.

Comment: @Grundy but I execute setTimeout, not location.reload()!

Comment: @LelioFaieta, parameters evaluate before calling function, so you code now equivalent next: `var func = location.reload(), delay=3600000 - ((new Date) % 3600000); setTimeout(func, delay);`

Comment: @Grundy then how I should write my code to get that location.reload() is called by setTimeout? This is actually what I am asking for ;)

Comment: @LelioFaieta see my first comment :-)

Comment: @Grundy sorry I missed it. Will you turn it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this line of code

```
setTimeout(location.reload(),3600000 - ((new Date) % 3600000));
```

have a one problem, [`location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) call before [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), so your code equivalent next:

```
var func = location.reload(),
    delay = 3600000 - ((new Date) % 3600000);
setTimeout(func, delay);
```

You need pass reference to function like

```
setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location),3600000 - ((new Date) % 3600000));
```

OR

```
setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},3600000 - ((new Date) % 3600000));
```

Comment: I tried `3610000 - ((new Date) % 3600000)` to wait for 10 seconds more before reloading but page seems not to reload at all... what am I missing?

Comment: seems to work. Are you sure, that page not reload? for test you can use `console.log` instead `reload` and see output

Answer (score 0):

If you can cause the page to reload the first time from the server, the server could end a reload value that is the milliseconds to the start of the hour, then have it reload the full hour when the timer is reset.

This wouldn't work if the page does not reload from the server though, for instance if a laptop was woken up and the page was not reloaded somehow. (I don't know what browsers do in that case...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032211/how-to-reload-a-page-at-certain-hour-and-only-once-a-day?rq=1 looks like it has some variations as well, BTW.